# Google Endpoints Android Client Library for multiple api classes

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine

I split up the code for my endpoints api over several classes with the @endpoints.api decorator. This was the way recommended by Google ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#creating_an_api_implemented_with_multiple_classes)). Now I am trying to generate the Android client libraries using the command line tool. I can generate the library for one class using the following command

`endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs gradle api.HelloWorldApi`

and this works. But I have other classes that need to also be part of the library. eg.

`endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs gradle api.GoodbyeWorldApi`

I do not know how to generate one complete library encompassing both of these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Did some looking around endpointscfg file in google's tools folder and realized that it takes multiple remote.service files as arguments. So I was able to use the following command to create client libraries from all the classes
`endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java api.GoodbyeWorldApi api.HelloWorldApi -bs gradle`